# Microcontroller Evaluation board with SPI and 3.3V as logic high

Tags: microcontroller, spi, pll, 3.3v, texas-instruments

Are there some microcontroller evaluation boards that support SPI, and use 3.3V logic? I am only familiar with the Arduino Uno, which uses 5 Volt logic.

If such 3.3 Volt boards are available, which such boards would work for the purpose of configuring TI's PLL chip [TRF3765](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/trf3765.pdf)?

I would prefer not to add a level shifter on my PCB.

Comment: Did you try a 3.3V Arduino?

Comment: Any hints to size, pins, 8/16/32-bit etc. would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest for example the Atmel Xplained boards as they are cheap and easy to use. They can also invert the level of the logic signals programmatically. It got 3.3V logic as well. The IDE is free, good and based on visual studio. It is possible to flash these with an USB cable.

Here is one example of the boards:

[Atmel AVR XMEGA-A1 Xplained kit](http://store.atmel.com/PartDetail.aspx?q=p:10500183#tc%3adescription)

Comment: Thanks for replying.
So this board would have some kind of a GUI with it and I could set it up very simply? And what is the clock for SPI since the PLL chip that I'm using requires 20MHz clock as maximum as you could see from datasheet.
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/trf3765.pdf

Comment: @user33379: There is no GUI application that let you set up the SPI if that is what you are asking. In the datasheet is says: "Synchronous clock rates up to 1/2 of the device clock frequency" and the max clock frequency is 32MHz so I _assume_ maximum 16 MHz, but this should be investigated closely. If you need that fast SPI communication go for a ARM MCU instead.

Comment: :Actually I want slower clock coz the PLL requires clock lower than 20MHz, I think 16MHz is good enough. 
You mentioned that it is easy to setup so what you were saying was that the IDE is easy to use?
Do you have some other suggestions for these kind of boards with even less features? I say the datasheet and I think there are way more features than what I actually need. Thanks very much!!

Comment: @user33379: I think the IDE is good and therefore makes it easier to get started. There are also SPI example code available. I suggest you check store.atmel.com for other Atmel product that might fit your needs. Also check for example st.com for STM8 microcontrollers. Please upvote/accept answer if this information helped you partly/fully.